# Calling a private static void method

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I have a `private static void` method namely  `convertToIp` in the class `EllaDtoConverter` that has a private constructor. If I try to create an instance of the class, it throws an exception. The code is provided,

```
public final class EllaDtoConverter {

    private EllaDtoConverter() {
        throw new PrivateConstructorException();
    }

private static void convertToIp( final IrisBo irisBo, EllaRequestDto request ) {

        if( !isNull( irisBo.getDevice() ) ) {
            request.setIp( irisBo.getDevice().getIpAddress() );
        }
    }

    // ..... some code 
}
```

I can create the instances of the  `IrisBo` and the `EllaRequestDto` and pass inside the method. Do I have an option to call the `convertToIp` method outside from another class (even with using the reflection)?

Comment: "If I try to create an instance of the class, it throws an exception" because the only thing in the constructor is `throw new PrivateConstructorException();`. You're not meant to create an instance of the class.

Comment: is there another method, which is not private and which calls that method?

Comment: You won't be able to create an object of the class from outside, as the constructor is *private*.

Comment: ... but you also don't need to have an instance in order to call a static method. (You need to use reflection to call a private method, though, and hope there is no SecurityManager to prevent that)

Comment: @NicholasK it's about calling the static method, not about calling the constructor

Comment: Use reflection: `EllaDtoConverter.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertToIp", IrisBo.class, EllaRequestDto.class).invoke(null, yourargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `junit` tag I assume you want to know if it is possible to test the method.

I suggest you [this article](https://anthonysciamanna.com/2016/02/14/should-private-methods-be-tested.html) which basically says that you shouldn't be testing private methods (static or not doesn't really matter) on their own.

The main idea is that unit testing should test the contract that your module is exposing, assuring that whoever calls you get what it expects from you, and private methods are not part of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

As @bracco23 written before, you should read an article about testing private methods.
However, if you have already decided to do it (despiting all this negative aspects which comes with testing them), there is a special framework called **PowerMockito**. PowerMockito allows us to test private or static methods.